# How to determine the isolated singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> problem:
> Calculate integral   :    $\int _0 ^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^a(x-1)}dx$

0＜a＜1

We should determine the isolated singularity,i think it only possibly has  0.since we know $\lim_{z\ to  1} \frac{\log z}{(z-1)} =0$.But hint indicate 1 is a simple pole,The following is the prompt words：

It extends analytically to$ (0,\infty)$ from above apparent singularity at $z = 1$ is removable. However, the extension to $(0, \infty) $
from below has a simple pole at z = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{a}\pars{x - 1}}\,\dd x} =
\left.\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\nu} - 1 \over x - 1}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ -a}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\color{red}{1^{-}}\ -\ 1}\ -\ x^{\pars{\color{red}{\nu + 1}} - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ -a}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-\partiald{}{\nu}
\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}\Gamma\pars{-\nu}
\cos\pars{-\bracks{\nu + 1}\pi}
\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ -a}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\left.\partiald{}{\nu}
\pi\cot\pars{\nu\pi}\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ -a} =
\left.
\pi^{2}\csc^{2}\pars{\nu\pi}\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ -a}
\\[5mm] = &
\bbx{\pi^{2}\csc^{2}\pars{\pi a}} \\ &
\end{align}